# Hibernate NLS Setting in spring data jpa

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, nls

I check similar post and most of suggest that use alter session with native command.
I want to learn that is there any avaliable configuration set oracle nls session for spring jpa or set in jvm parameters which my application and jpa queries work with this nls configurations